# Best way to conditionally apply utility classes on a component based on its props

Tags: css, reactjs, vue.js, refactoring, vue-component

I am using Vue.js (though my question is valid for any framework) where you can pass a simple object and the `truthy` keys apply as classes.
Eg. `<div :class="{ 'class1': prop1, 'class2', prop2 }">Hello</div>`. If `prop1` is true, `class1` applies. If both props are true, both `class1` and `class2` apply.

Also, I am using Atomic/Utiliy classes. So, there are no classes with multiple properties in them, instead, for `color:red` I use `C(red)`, for `background-color:blue` I use `Bgc(blue)` and so on...

With this as the base I have a button component that has the following props:

1. *Theme* - with values primary, secondary.
2. *Inverted* - true/false
3. *Disabled* - true/value

Creating a class object for that number of interrelated props becomes a bit messy:

```
{
'Bdc(color1) Bdc(color2):h Bdc(color3):a': this.theme === 'primary' && !this.linkOnly,
'Bdc(color4) Bdc(color5):h Bdc(color5):a': this.theme === 'positive' && !this.linkOnly,
'Bdc(color1) Bdc(color2):h Bdc(color4):a': this.theme === 'negative' && !this.linkOnly,
'Bdc(color3) Bdc(color3):h Bdc(color3):a': (this.theme === 'default' && !this.linkOnly) ||
(!this.theme && !this.linkOnly),

'C(color1) C(color2):h C(color3):a':
    this.theme === 'primary' && (this.linkOnly || this.inverted),
'C(color3) C(color4):h C(color5):a':
    this.theme === 'positive' && (this.linkOnly || this.inverted),
'C(color2) C(color3):h C(color4):a':
    this.theme === 'negative' && (this.linkOnly || this.inverted),
'C(color5) C(color6):h C(color7):a':
    (this.theme === 'default' && (this.linkOnly || this.inverted)) ||
    (!this.theme && (this.linkOnly || this.inverted)),
'C(color1)': !(this.linkOnly || this.inverted)
```

}

As you can see, the conditions there are difficult to read. And adding some new prop will make it more difficult to implement correctly.

One more important thing: the atomic CSS library I am using requires that the final classes be present in the code because it parses and puts them in the CSS. So `'Bgc(' + someVariable + ')'` won't work as it isn't a final class we want.

I am looking for help on how these conditions can be refactored to make styling manageable with atomic/utility classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could move all the logic to `computed` property:

```
function getBtnClass () {
  let classes = []
  if (this.theme === 'primary') classes.push('Bdc(color1)', 'Bdc(color2):h')
  ...
  return classes.join(' ')
}
```

And pass it to the template: `<div class='getBtnClass'>...</div>`

Comment: I actually have my mentioned big object being returned from a computed property only. But then the issue is that the object is huge, the conditions are complex. In your example, the long condition of my code just moves inside `if` conditions. Or is there something else I am missing in your code?

Comment: I've updated the answer, so my idea is about turning classList into array and push there classes one-by-one. Could it make conditions less complex? You may also try `switch..case` syntax, it will make your code more readable.